# How to make string paragraph easier to read for source code

Tags: powershell, formatting

I'm writing a script in PowerShell and it will display a long message. Basically, I'm trying to figure out how the break the string into multiple lines, yet it will still display as a single line.

```
$paragraph = "This is a test to create a single-lined string,
             but it doesn't seem to work. I would prefer
             to make source code easier to read."
```

Intended Output:

`This is a test to create a single-lined string, but it doesn't seem to work. I would prefer to make source code easier to read.`

Actual Output:

```
This is a test to create a single-lined string.`
but it doesn't seem to work. I would prefer
to make source code easier to read.
```

I've tried using backticks, but this produces the same result. Anyone know the correct way to format my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
$paragraph = "This is a test to create a single-lined string, " +
             "but it doesn't seem to work. I would prefer " +
             "to make source code easier to read."
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a [here-string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx) and `-replace`:

```
$paragraph = @"
This is a test to create a single-lined string.
But it doesn't seem to work. I would prefer
to make source code easier to read.
"@ -replace "`n"," "
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better solution, but I've gone for this approach in the past to make things readable:

```
$paragraph = "This is a test to create a single-lined string, "
$paragraph += "but it doesn't seem to work. I would prefer "
$paragraph += "to make source code easier to read."
```